# Open a file extension with a java program

Tags: java, windows

I have a jar (prog.jar) that prints

**Hello World , The file is: args[1]**

and I'd like to associate the files named *.myext to be opened with that command:

```
 java -jar prog.jar example.myext
```

Using Windows (7) how can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

every google request gives a bunch of advises, why ask on developers forum?

http://www.winvistaclub.com/t19.html

Answer (score 0):

Some JDK installs (older ones) didn't create the file associations for you.  The newer JDK and JRE installations do.

Just create the proper file association on your system.  You can probably run this script in order to accomplish it:

```
:: register_java.bat
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
:: this script creates a file association for executable .jar files
ECHO Creating .jar file association...
ECHO JAVA_HOME is %JAVA_HOME%
IF NOT DEFINED JAVA_HOME GOTO :FAIL
REG ADD "HKCR\jarfile" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "Executable Jar File" /f
REG ADD "HKCR\jarfile\shell" /ve /f
REG ADD "HKCR\jarfile\shell\open" /ve /f
ECHO REG ADD "HKCR\jarfile\shell\open\command" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "\"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javaw.exe\" -jar \"%%1\" %%*" /f
REG ADD "HKCR\jarfile\shell\open\command" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "\"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javaw.exe\" -jar \"%%1\" %%**" /f
REG ADD "HKLM\jarfile" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "Executable Jar File" /f
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\jarfile\shell" /ve /f
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\jarfile\shell\open" /ve /f
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\jarfile\shell\open\command" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "\"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javaw.exe\" -jar \"%%1\" %%*" /f
ECHO Finished creating .jar file association for executable .jar files.
PAUSE
GOTO EOF
:FAIL
ECHO Script failed. JAVA_HOME not defined.
PAUSE
```